# Unit digit of a number of given form

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider a number of the form p = (n^2+n)/9

Can it have a unit digit of 9?
How do you prove it mathematically?

Here's my work:
Let's consider the possible unit digits for n:

If the unit digit of n is 0, then n(n+1)/2 would also have a unit digit of 0.

If the unit digit of n is 1, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 2. The product of 1 and 2 is 2, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 1.

If the unit digit of n is 2, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 3. The product of 2 and 3 is 6, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 3.

If the unit digit of n is 3, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 4. The product of 3 and 4 is 12, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 6.

If the unit digit of n is 4, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 5. The product of 4 and 5 is 20, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 0.

If the unit digit of n is 5, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 6. The product of 5 and 6 is 30, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 5.

If the unit digit of n is 6, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 7. The product of 6 and 7 is 42, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 1.

If the unit digit of n is 7, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 8. The product of 7 and 8 is 56, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 8.

If the unit digit of n is 8, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 9. The product of 8 and 9 is 72, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 6.

If the unit digit of n is 9, then the unit digit of (n+1) would be 0. The product of 9 and 0 is 0, and dividing it by 2 gives a unit digit of 0.

But I am not able to prove it using number theory.....

How shall we do it?

Comment: Your first sentence mentions division by 9, but the rest of the question uses division by 2?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  The header refers to division by $9$.  Is that what you meant?  Or did you mean division by $2$?  At least the latter is always an integer....  Assuming you meant $2$, note that you only need to check the first $10$ natural numbers (why?).

Comment: If a number divided by $9$ has unit digit $9$ , it must have unit digit $1$ , in particular it must be odd. But $n^2+n=n(n+1)$ is obviously even.